# Why does a reference to an array change to a hash reference when passed to a subroutine

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, hashmap

I came across this issue in a tool I'm attempting to fix and don't understand what causes the array reference change to a hash reference. It only occurs when the array ref is listed after the hash ref in the parameters, which makes me think it's due the way the parameters are received.

I don't have the code from the tool but the below code recreates what was happening.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub PassArrRef{
    my @array = [0,1,2,3,4];
    my %hash = {0,'a',1,'b',2,'c'};
    RecieveHashRef(\%hash, \@array)
}

sub RecieveHashRef{
    my %hash = %{$_[0]};
    my $arrayref = shift;
    print $arrayref;
}

PassArrRef();
```

This code outputs a Hash reference.

Comment: Please run your code and then [edit] and fix the errors it throws.

Comment: The code as is doesn't print anything (as you declare two subs but don't run any). Please post a runnable example.

Comment: My bad I forgot the subroutine call, will add now.

Comment: You also use the wrong syntax to declare your variables. `{}` and `[]` make references. So your `@array` is a one-element list that has an array ref in it, and your `%has` actually throws a warning when it's created because it uses a hash reference as its only key, but has no vaue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because in `ReceiveHashRef` you are directly referencing the first positional parameter, `$_[0]` and then on the next line calling `shift` which takes the first element of the positional parameters.  The same thing.

The typical way to consume the subroutine arguments would be:

```
my($hashref, $arrayref) = @_;
```

Totally fixed, your code should look like this.  The `diagnostics` pragma will give you much more expansive explanations of errors.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

sub PassArrRef{
    my @array = (0,1,2,3,4);
    my %hash = (0,'a',1,'b',2,'c');
    ReceiveHashRef(\%hash, \@array)
}

sub ReceiveHashRef{
    my($hashref, $arrayref) = @_;
    print "hash ref: $hashref, array ref: $arrayref\n";
}

PassArrRef();
```

And make liberal use of https://perldoc.perl.org/!

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I was assuming the $_[0] shifted the first parameter for some reason.